# React HTML Select Option won't work in Chrome

Tags: html, reactjs

I am developing my first project on React an I need a select option to sort some items. I did the sorting and it works fine but in Chrome when I select an option nothing happens. I did the same thing with a button and it works but with option it wont.

My example (it won't console.log on Chrome but it does on Firefox):

```
<select name="sort" id="sort">
    <option value="ascending" onClick={() => {
        console.log("clicked");
        //actually I am calling a function here
    }}>
        Ascending
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use `onChange` on select element, instead on option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `onChange` on `select` tag not on `option` tag

Use like this

```
 <select name="sort" id="sort" onChange={handleChange}>
    <option value="ascending">Ascending</option>
    <option value="descending">Descending</option>
  </select>
```

function

```
const handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
```

Check this live example - https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-monad-vdto2

Comment: this seems to work on Chrome but how i take the value of the option (because i have 2 options, ascending and descending) and i m calling 2 different functions for each sort?

Comment: @MariosG check now.

Comment: @MariosG please accept/vote for this if answer is helpful for you.